# Codeception helper to use $I without passing it into the helper

Tags: php, codeception, acceptance-testing

I wanted to create some reusable methods that use a collection of different AcceptanceTester methods in Form Helper.  The functions don't fit for a PageObject, and since StepObjects inherit from AcceptanceTester and you can inject them replacing AcceptanceTester in methods, and I don't want to create a Form StepObject and inject both AcceptTester and Form, which seem sloppy.

Is there a way to access $I in a helper? It seems like a usecase for a helper. Or is this not the way you're supposed to use helpers?  If not could someone explain their use with an real example, the docs in this section don't seem to help my understanding.  I can see I could pass in $I to the helper, but I'd rather inject two StepObjects, passing in $I just looks wrong.

**HELPER**

```
<?php
namespace Helper;

class Form extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public function seeFormError($message) {

        $I = ???

        $I->see($message, 'small.error);
    }
}
```

**USE**

```
protected $form;

protected function _inject(\Helper\Form $form)
{
    $this->form = $form;
}

public function login() 
{
    $this->form->seeFormError('Enter a valid email');
}
```

Comment: You can access methods of other modules in this way: $this->getModule('PhpBrowser')->see();

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
namespace Codeception\Module;

class UnitHelper extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public function seeFormError($message) 
    {
        $I = $this;
        $I->see($message, 'small.error');
    }
}
```

Use $I = $this. You are working on the object, which you want to extend.

After this, you can use the new method in your cest/test like all others `$I->seeFormErrors($message);`

Try to fix your namespace. The example I took from my unit test helper.

Comment: As a bonus point, to enable intellisense, you can type hint variable via phpdoc.